# iron-router does not render template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

I have installed the atmosphere package iron:router for my meteor application. I am trying to add a simple route like this:

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout',
loadingTemplate: 'loading',
notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

Router.route('/', {
    name : 'homeIndex'
});
```

I defined a template:

```
<template name="homeIndex">
    <h1>Test for my meteor application</h1>
</template>
```

And I add a yield - field to my layoutTemplate:

```
<template name="layout">
    <div class="container">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

But still when I go to `'/'`, I don't see anything of my template.

Also when I'm trying to add another route with another template, it doesn't work. I have installed the package through this command: `meteor add iron:router`

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked at my console in the browser, I saw the iron router package was throwing an exception that EJSON was undefined in the javascript of the package. I installed the EJSON package with the command `meteor add ejson`, and it was fixed! But thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a template when a user goes to a particular route, you should use `this.render('templateName');`. In your case, you only defined a [named route](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#named-routes), but you didn't specify which template to render.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('homeIndex');
}, {
    name: 'homeIndex'
});
```